# Scanner not getting declared, but why?! also, it is saying I can't print the global variable "line"? but why?

Tags: java

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class file_reading 
{
    Scanner scanner;

    try 
    {
        FileReader reader = new FileReader("toread.txt");
        scanner = new Scanner(reader);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.print("hello incorrect");
    }

    String line = scanner.nextLine();

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a few errors here, first is that you write try outside of method which is illegal, you must have method and inside his block(between { }) you will write code.
Reason why you can't print line is probably because you are calling non-static variable from static method(main)

Answer (score 2):

You have to put all the code inside a method. Except the declaration of Scanner.

You could declare it inside your main-method like this. Then it's visible only inside this method.

```
 Scanner scanner;
```

Or you define it outside of the main method as a static member.

```
 static Scanner scanner;
```

The it's available throughout the class.

And you have to put

```
String line = scanner.nextLine();
System.out.println(line);
```

inside your try/catch-block. Otherwise the compiler assumes that "scanner" might not have been initialized, as you initialize it only inside this block but want to use it outside. And you'd get a warning that "line" is unknown because you instantiated this inside the try/catch too, which makes it unreachable for all code outside the curly braces.

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class file_reading 
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
      Scanner scanner;

      try 
      {
         FileReader reader = new FileReader("toread.txt");
         scanner = new Scanner(reader);

         String line = scanner.nextLine();
         System.out.println(line);

      } catch (Exception e) {
         System.err.print("hello incorrect");
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: "if you want to define it globally." but you'd have to make it `static` also.

Comment: That's true! My bad, sorry. ;)   Re-edited my answer.